# embedding a hyperlink in facebook feed popup dialog does not work

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I am getting stuck with embedding a hyperlink with a text in my facebook "feed" dialog, the following is what i have tried, i tried to set the json properties with text and href to FB.ui, but it does not seem to work as expected; when i bring up the corresponding facebook popup dialog, i cannot click on the text i embedded with a hyperlink, i also cannot do any copy and past operation on the dialog.

```
FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    display : 'popup',
    name : 'Facebook Dialogs',
    picture : 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption : 'Reference Documentation',
    description : 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
    properties : [{
        text : 'value1',
        href : 'http://facebook.com',
    }]
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
```

notice that adding `properties :[{text : 'value1',href : 'http://facebook.com',}]` does not produce the effect being expected. I expect it to produce a active hyperlink for a text in the dialog and i click on the text and it will take me to another page when the dialog is shown, but the hyperlink is not active and click-able in the popup dialog.

It will be greatly appreciated if anyone can shed some light with it.

Thanks
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

The link is not active in the popup dialog, but once the post is published, it will work as expected.

So, make the post and check your wall.

**Edit:**

This works for me:

```
....,
properties:
{
    "Google me":
    {
        text: 'link', 
        href: 'http://google.com/'
    }
},
....
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, and i modified the code according to your suggestion, but unluckily your suggestion was not able to solve the issue, if use {text:.., "href":...}, i would see hyperlink as a text shown in the dialog and it is not click-able either; i also tried the following form properties : {"Look at user reviews":{
      "text" : 'value1',
      "href" : 'http://www.facebook.com',
     }}
it does not work either, by not working , i mean the hyperlink is not active for me to click

Comment: As I've edited the answer, the link is not active in the popup, but once it is published, you'll see that the link is active to click

Comment: Hi Sahil again, thanks for the prompt response, i would like to embed a hyperlink with a text in a dialog, not sure if it can be achieved, now it seems this json properties alludes this possibility.... besides, when my feed is posted to wall, the entire post is click-able but that link to the address specified in the "Link".  I am still willing to find out how to get the hyperlink to be active in the feed dialog....

Comment: But it works for me, check out the edit. In the popup it isnt active, but when the actual post is published the link is active

Comment: Sorry Sahil you miss the point, i know what you are saying works in some sense, but that is not what i want to achieve, i am willing to embed a hyperlink with a text in the facebook dialog, but playing around the json properties for FB.ui, it seems the text and href does not seem to work (click-able) in the dialog.

Comment: Lol, am stiull confused what you are trying to say, may be others too. So it would be better if you can post a screenshot showing that what is not clickable and what you want to do

Comment: sorry sahil, it seems i dont have enough credits to append an image, and i think my point is obvious, it seems you are trying to allude that it is not possible to embed an active hyperlink in a dialog, right? By being active, i mean it is click-able in the dialog and it can direct me to the place specified in the properties{text..., href...}, I also wonder about the purpose of and usage of the FB.ui's properties (text and href)...

Comment: Check my wall- https://www.facebook.com/sahilmittal, the first post. I used the `properties`. Isnt this what you want?

Comment: Hi Sahil what i want to achieve is a click-able hyperlink in the dialog, it might gives the user a chance to review something else relevant before feed gets posted to wall.

Comment: it seems you concur that the hyperlink is not active in the dialog, but i want it to be active if possible; but the question is how....

Comment: `click-able hyperlink in the dialog, it might gives the user a chance to review`- i got it, but this by design so you cant help.  Nothing is clickable on a dialog, its just a screenshot of what's going to be posted.! Logical eh?

Comment: then i would wonder why there is a parameter of FB.ui (i.e. properties of text and href) that seems to allow me to add a hyperlink.   and note, after feed gets posted, it usually takes the "Link" parameter of FB.ui.

Comment: This `property` is very useful. If I want to add some links in the feed along with description I use this.

Comment: thanks Sahil, i think i understand what you mean, but the properties parameter (with text and href) also cannot work on my side even after the feed gets posted, those properties do not show up, take the google example given in your response above, i will be expecting to see ""Google me : Link" and the link has a hyperlink embedded, but i cannot find them after it gets posted on my wall, note they can be viewed in the dialog with inactive hyperlink, but after it is posted, they disappear on the wall. Please kindly shed some lights on it.

Comment: Actually its not visible in the wall but if you check on your timeline, its visible. https://www.facebook.com/me. I'm not sure about this behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot Sahil for the prompt response, appreciated.

Comment: I'll post this as a bug and will let you know